# How to get the name of the Parent component in Child component in angular 2?

Tags: angular, parent-child, mean-stack

Suppose I have three components: **C1, C2, and C3**.

I want to make C2 the child of **both C1 and C3**.
And according to the fact which component is the parent of C2 want to show HTML text - "**C1 is my parent**" or "**c3 is my parent**".
This is the superficial form of my problem.
I want to access the name of the parent component in c2, then will change its innerHTML accordingly.

How to access the name of the parent component in angular2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply pass something that will describe your parent component to a child by `@Input`.

Example of child component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `
    <div>{{ parentName }} is my parent</div>
  `,
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() parentName: string;
}
```

First parent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'first-parent',
  template: `
    <child-component parentName="'first-parent-component'" />
  `,
})
export class FirstParentComponent {
}
```

Second parent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'second-parent',
  template: `
    <child-component parentName="'second-parent-component'" />
  `,
})
export class SecondParentComponent {
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I am using it but I thought there must be some other particular way to do the job, with which we can fetch the name of the parent component directly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the the `ActivatedRoute`. where you can use the `activatedRoute.snapshot.component`

And then if you want it in an if statement for type comparison =>

```
if(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.component === YourComponentParentName)
```

Do stuff....